# Flexbox sidemenu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following implementation i came up with for a sidemenu works fine

https://jsbin.com/getotijela/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
    a
</div>

<div class="content">
    <span id="clickable">
        basdasdasdasdas
    </span>
</div>
<div>

<script>

document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener('click',function(){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0]
    el.className  = "menuClosed"
})

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    background-color:red;
}

.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

.menu{
    width:200px;
    /* left:20px; */
    background-color:red;
}

.menuClosed{
    width:0px;
    background-color:red;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}


.content{
    background-color:yellow;
    flex:1;
}
```

but what it does is collapse the sidemenu to a `width` of `0` ( as i've instructed it to). What i was aiming for was: having the sidemenu move to the left as many units as it's width, something that in the past i would achieve by modifying the `left`css property.

In other words, i dont want the menu to collapse to a width of 0, just have it move out of sight

How could i achieve something similar to that in flexbox if at all?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: added it to a jsbin but its not that the implementation is problematic, its just that as a beginner i dont know how to go from that to what i actually wanted to achieve

Comment: It's important to post all relevant code so that we can see the problem you're having. You should also post the code in the question itself (or your question is likely to be closed). https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: okay edited , still think code in itself is relatively unrelated as the implementation im after would be different

Answer (score 3):

@PossessWithin Why would you use a translateX for that ?

You should use the flexbox-shrink and flexbox-basis property's they are made especially for these cases.

I made a fiddle check it out here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyx9p2Ly/3/)

```
<aside class="sidebar is-visible">
    <p class="sidebar-content">
      Put all your content inside of here since this keeps the width of your sidebar <br>(so a div with the width       you want the sidebar to be).
    </p>
  </aside>
  <main class="content">
    <button class="toggle-sidebar">Toggle sidebar</button>
    <p>
      scale this content
    </p>
  </main>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
  flex-direction: column;

  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}


.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;

  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar.is-visible  ~ .content {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

/* Animation */
.content {
  transition: flex-basis .1s cubic-bezier(.465, .183, .153, .946);
  will-change: flex-basis;
}

.sidebar.is-visible  ~ .content {
  transition: flex-basis .3s cubic-bezier(.465, .183, .153, .946);
}


.sidebar-content {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Please vote this up since it's the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Also you should use HTML5 semantic tags instead of divs. They are way more practical in use of Javascript and readability for later changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
    a
</div>

<div class="content">
    <span id="clickable">
        basdasdasdasdas
    </span>
</div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
    background-color:red;
}

.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

.menu{
    width:200px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    background-color:red;
}

.menuClosed{
    background-color:red;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    margin-right: -200px;
}

.content{
    background-color:yellow;
    flex:1;
}
```

I have changed the "menuClosed" class by moving it to the left with a transform: translateX(-200px). To make the screen move back to the right, I have added a negative margin right of the same size.

This may not be the best practice - I'm open minded to hear other solutions!

Also, as a plus, I have changed your Javascript code to toggle the class, making it work to open and close on click, instead of opening only.

You can see the [new code here, on Codepen](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/XEEWLP). I hope it helps you!